# Deploy lumen with apache2

Tags: laravel, lumen

I have an application that in development work correctly but if I set under apache2 give me this error.

> [Thu Apr 16 20:50:41.239221 2020] [php7:error] [pid 16447] [client
>   77.32.83.227:17606] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Return value of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::setStatusCode() must
>   be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\object, instance
>   of Illuminate\Http\Response returned in
>   /var/www/app-backend/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php:453\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /var/www/app-backend/vendor/illuminate/http/Response.php(35):
>   Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response->setStatusCode(500)\n#1
>   /var/www/app-backend/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Exceptions/Handler.php(168):
>   Illuminate\Http\Response->__construct('prepareResponse(Object(Laravel\Lumen\Http\Request),
>   Object(TypeError))\n#3
>   /var/www/app-backend/app/Exceptions/Handler.php(52):
>   Laravel\Lumen\Exceptions\Handler->render(Object(Laravel\Lumen\Http\Request),
>   Object(TypeError))\n#4
>   /var/www/app-backend/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RegistersExceptio in /var/www/app-backend/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php on
>   line 453 [Thu Apr 16 20:50:41.239315 2020] [php7:error] [pid 16447]
>   [client 77.32.83.227:17606] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to
>   undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Application::handleException() in
>   /var/www/app-backend/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RegistersExceptionHandlers.php:67\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /var/www/app-backend/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RegistersExceptionHandlers.php(55):
>   Laravel\Lumen\Application->handleShutdown()\n#1 [internal function]:
>   Laravel\Lumen\Application->Laravel\Lumen\Concerns\{closure}()\n#2
>   {main}\n  thrown in
>   /var/www/app-backend/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RegistersExceptionHandlers.php
>   on line 67

I try everything but I can't run app into production webserver.

Thanks,
Jacopo

Comment: did you clear the cache and dump composer autoload ?

Comment: `composer clear-cache && composer dumpautoload`

Same error on Apache